# skip generic parameter on demand

Tags: delphi, generics

I found this definition of an generic class  in the web :

```
  TVertex<T> = class
  public
    Name: String;
    OutputAttributes: TVertexOutputAttributes;
    Marker: Boolean;
    Data: T; // User-defined data attribute
    function HasAdditionalAttributes: Boolean;
    constructor Create();
    procedure Mark;
    procedure UnMark;
  end;
```

a single instance of a TVertex class is created with the following line of code :

```
  A := TVertex<Integer>.Create();
  A.Name := 'A';
```

in this example we define T as Integer data Type. My question goes now like this :

If my use case does not need any assigend datatype T it would be much better / logical if I can skip the specification on the datatype.  I failed with :

```
   A := TVertex<>.Create();
  A.Name := 'A';
```

Any change to avoid the handover of the datatype at the create process ???

Comment: Sure. Make a non-generic version of your class, if you don't need generics.

Comment: I agree.  If you like the TVertex functionality, and don't want to re-write it as a non-generic, then just use Int, then ignore the Data field.

Comment: In Java, there's a Void type for exactly this situation to make clear, that you don't use it at all (if the generic class is in 3rd party code, then you may need that):
so there's no equivalent for that in Delpih, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are explicitly asking for has one obvious flaw. What will the compiler do with this declaration?

```
Data: T; // User-defined data attribute
```

If you don't supply a `T`, then the compiler doesn't know what to do.

This observation leads us to one possible approach. If you don't want to supply `T` then presumably you don't want the class to contain this member. How can it contain that member if its type is not supplied? So define a non-generic version:

```
type
  TVertex = class
  public
    Name: String;
    OutputAttributes: TVertexOutputAttributes;
    Marker: Boolean;
  end;
```

And then derive your generic version from this:

```
type
  TVertex<T> = class(TVertex)
  public
    Data: T; // User-defined data attribute
  end;
```

Clearly you would need to determine in which class the methods should be declared and implemented. Clearly any methods that did not rely on `Data` could be implemented in the non-generic class.