# graph class for generic and non generic vertex types

Tags: delphi, generics

a vertex class with an optional data field has been discussed [SKIP GENERIC PARAMETER ON DEMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269109/skip-generic-parameter-on-demand); The best solution for me looks like this :

```
type
  TVertex = class
  public
    Name: String;
    OutputAttributes: TVertexOutputAttributes;
    Marker: Boolean;
  end;


type
  TVertex<T> = class(TVertex)
  public
    Data: T; // User-defined data attribute
  end;
```

While writing now the connected graph class I figured out a further problem :

```
TGraph = Class
  private
  Vertices: TObjectList<TVertex>;
  ....
  function addVertex(u: TVertex): Integer;
  function removeVertex(u: TVertex): TVertex;
 end;
```

all function request the non generic version of my vertex class Tvertex right now.  What is the best way to extend my Graph class to work with both vertex class definitions ( generic Tvertex  and non generic one TVertex  ) ?   I tried the following code without success.

```
//  a generic class working with 2 Tvertex class definitions ... 
//  this code does npot work :-(  
TGraph<MyVertexType> = Class
  private
  Vertices: TObjectList<MyVertexType>;
  ....
  function addVertex(u: MyVertexType): Integer;
  function removeVertex(u: MyVertexType): MyVertexType;
 end;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by: *all function request the non generic version of my vertex class right now*?

Comment: Seems to me you are looking for a visitor pattern as a handler for the generic vertex

Comment: I suppose the most relevant question is - What is the problem with it as it is?  Surely if there are issues to be resolved it is at the implementation level.  How can we provide guidance if we don't know what the implementation is?

Comment: I need help on TGraph<MyVertexType> = Class ...., hope the problem is now much better described

Comment: By the way, please don't say "does not work". Your code produces a compiler error. You should report that error verbatim and identify the line on which it occurs. As it happens, I can work it out this time, but that's not always the case. And what if we get it wrong? Perhaps there are more errors than the obvious one that we can see. Be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will not compile because you use `TObjectList<T>` which requires that `T` be a class. There is no constraint that enforces that. So you could add that constraint:

```
type
  TGraph<MyVertexType: class> = class
    FVertices: TObjectList<MyVertexType>;
    ...
  end;
```

I do wonder whether you've fully thought through the lifetime ownership of the vertices. Using `TObjectList<T>` would imply that you intend the list to own the objects and destroy them when they are removed from the list. In which case

```
function removeVertex(u: MyVertexType): MyVertexType;
```

does not make sense.

Note that the definition above does not allow the graph class any knowledge of the capabilities of `MyVertexType` beyond the fact that it is a class. So perhaps you should constrain `MyVertexType` to be a vertex:

```
type
  TGraph<MyVertexType: TVertex> = class
    ...
  end;
```

This will allow the graph container to call vertex methods on its members.

Comment: I'm still in trouble because  TGraph<MyVertexType: TVertex> = class ...   will not allow me to pass a TVertex<T> vertex type class with some addition user data T to the Procedure graph init procedure . As TGraph<MyVertexType: class> = class helps to get my stuff compiled I will create a further question now on the class design

Comment: You can pass an instantiated `TVertex<T>` surely. It's very hard to do all this in comments!

Answer (score -1):

```
type
  TVertex = class
  public
    Name: String;
    OutputAttributes: TVertexOutputAttributes;
    Marker: Boolean;
  end;

  TIntVertex = class(TVertex)
  public
    Data: Integer;
  end;

  TSomethingElseVertex = class(TVertex)
  public
    Data: TSomethingElse;
  end;

TGraph = class(TObjectList<TVertex>)
// any additional methods
end;
```

...

```
var
  Graph: TGraph;
  Vertex: TVertex;
```

...

```
Vertex := TIntVertex.Create;
Graph.Add(Vertex);
Vertex := Graph.Last;
if (Vertex is TIntVertex) then
  (Vertex as TIntVertex).Data := 42;
```